# How to align a pie chart to the left in highcharts js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vuejs3

I'm trying to pin a pie chart to the left.
A negative marginLeft and center: ['20%', '50%'] don't give me what i need
since when changing the screen width the position of the chart also changes.
I am using **Vue 3 composition api**

```
series: [{
            center: ['20%', '90%'],
            size: '150%',
            innerSize: '65%',
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'Valid',
                    y: 10,
                    color: '#13CE66'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Failed Verification',
                    y: 5,
                    color: '#FF4949'
                }
            ],
             showInLegend: true
        }]
```

It should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `chart.marginLeft` property

**Example config:**

```
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    marginLeft: -230
  },
```

**Example demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k52j7m9x/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft